# When Converting ADP files to ACCDB do server based Stored Procs get converted?

Tags: ms-access, adp

When updating an Access 2003 ADP file to an Access 2010 AccDB file are SQL server linked tables, views and specifically stored procs "updated"?

I am finding that I need to redo a fair amount of code around calling parameterized stored procs.

Comment: How are you ding this 'update'?

Comment: ADP/MDB -> ACCDB conversion only affects the actual ADP/MDB file. Sprocs stored on the server are not affected, however queries stored in the ADP/MDB file *might* be. Things might change with how the sproc is executed. We need more specifics from you before we can help further.